# Approximating an integral by the value in the central point

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function.

I want to show that $$\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} f(z) dz = 2 \epsilon f(a) + O(\epsilon^2)$$ for small enough $\epsilon$.

For this I tried taking the Taylor approximation of $f$ around $a$, according to which for each $z\in [a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon]$ there exists $c\in [a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon]$ such that $f(z) = f(a) + f'(c)(z-a)$.

But I am not sure of how to integrate the remainder term $f'(c)(z-a)$, since it varies depending on the $z$.

Questions:

1. Is what I am trying to prove true?
2. If it is, how do I complete the proof?
3. If it isn't, is there a similar statement I could use, perhaps with stronger regularity conditions on $f$?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need stronger regularity conditions; in fact you only need to assume that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ for a stronger conclusion.

The *definition* of $f'(a)$ shows that $$f(a+t)=f(a)+tf'(a)+o(t).$$So $$\begin{align}\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}f&=\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon f(a+t)\,dt
\\&=\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon(f(a)+tf'(a)+o(t))\,dt
\\&=2\epsilon f(a)+o(\epsilon^2).\end{align}$$

**Edit:** I've been asked how the definition of the derivative shows that. Say $$E(t)=\frac{f(a+t)-f(a)}{t}-f'(a).$$ So $\lim_{t\to0}E(t)=0$, or $E(t)=o(1)$. Rearranging the definition of $E$ gives $$f(a+t)=f(a)+tf'(a)+tE(t)=f(a)+tf'(a)+to(1)=f(a)+tf'(a)+o(t).$$

Comment: How does the definition of the derivative show that?

Comment: @Jsevillamol See edit...

Comment: Why does $\lim_{t\to \infty}E(t) = 0$ imply $E(t)=o(1)$? If for example $E(t)=t$ then we have that $\lim_{t\to \infty}E(t) = 0$ but $E(t)=o(t)$

Comment: When I said $E(t)=o(1)$  meant $o(1) (t\to0)$. (There's no $\lim_{t\to\infty}$ anywhere in what I wrote.) The _definition_ of "$E(t)=o(1) (t\to0$" is $\lim_{t\to0}E(t)=0$. There are big problems with the second sentence in your comment - I can't figure out what you actually meant there.

Comment: @Jsevillamol Hmm, _assuming_ that the $t\to\infty$ was the only typo in your comment: Yes, if $E(t)=t$ then $E(t)\to0$, so $E(t)=o(1)$. It's not true that $E=o(t)$,but if it was, so what? If $E(t)=t\sin(t)$ then $E(t)=o(t)$ and also $E(t)=o(1)$. i don't see waht the problem is

Comment: When you write $\lim_{t\to\infty}t=0$ that's clearly a typo. But when you say $t=o(t)$ it seems possible you really don't know what the notation means. Note that O and o are very different here. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations (but note that at that link they're only talking about $t\to\infty$, while we're dealing with $t\to0$.)